# How do I securely Implement registration on android app

Tags: android, mysql, django, password-encryption, user-registration

My system has a website: Running on Django 1.8 Framework ( Mysql and Apache). For website I am using Django Registration-redux.

Now I want to have an android app that has all the functionality of website. I am not sure what is the secure/best way to implement registration on Android.

My users can login/register by using website or app using same credentials stored on MySQL database.

By default, Django uses the PBKDF2 algorithm with a SHA256 hash, a password stretching mechanism recommended by NIST. 
The password attribute of a User object is a string in this format:
algorithm$iterations$salt$hash

Can someone direct me into right direction here? How secure PHP is ? and can I implementing similar encryption using PHP?

Comment: You can use `django-rest-framework` for this it has many tutorials as well

Comment: This is several different questions.